# Don't apply executable-make-buffer-file-executable-if-script-p to backup files

Tags: auto-save

I currently have

```
(add-hook 'after-save-hook
  'executable-make-buffer-file-executable-if-script-p)
```

in my config to automatically make scripts executable when saving them.  However, I personally don't like that this means that also the autosaved files ending in `~`, e.g., `myscript.sh~`, will automatically be rendered executable.

So my question is:

How can I automatically make only files not ending in `~` executable upon save?  I guess one has to write a small wrapper function, but my elisp skills are quite under-developed ... Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Your `myscript.sh` would already have been converted to an executable using `executable-make-buffer-file-executable-if-script-p`. So the created backup file `myscript.sh~` would also be an executable. `executable-make-buffer-file-executable-if-script-p` has nothing to do with it.

Comment: As an example, try the following: (1) `touch foo` (2) `chmod 744 foo` (3) Edit that file in emacs and save it (4) You will see a `foo~` created which is also an executable, because the original file was an executable.

Answer (score 1):

Wrap it with `backup-file-name-p`

```lisp
(defun my-maybe-make-executable ()
  "Maybe make file executable unless it is a backup file."
  (unless (backup-file-name-p buffer-file-name)
    (executable-make-buffer-file-executable-if-script-p)))
```

The issue pointed out by @Kaushalmodi seems like a deal breaker though, perhaps a better solution is to specify a separate backup file directory. And remove executable privileges from the whole backup directory when backups occur.